# Parsing paragraphs in applescript not working as expected

Tags: parsing, applescript, delimiter

**Posting the code is losing the formatting that is causing the issue, copying what I in the post will actually do what it should.** To bad that isn't an option in using the script, so I uploaded the script file [here](http://www.sendspace.com/file/zownb6) with an example of the text built in that is causing the issue. I will try to convey what the issue is still.

I am pulling text from mail.app. The emails I am parsing have within them a list of dates (amongst other things):

5/27/2012

5/28/2012

5/29/2012

5/30/2012

5/31/2012

6/1/2012

6/3/2012

6/4/2012

6/5/2012

6/6/2012

Now I'm trying to get the dates into a list. No problem I thought...

The following did NOT work:

*Using paragraphs did NOT work, returned the entire thing as a paragraph*

```
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to (ASCII character 13) -- (Carriage Return)

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to (ASCII character 10) -- (LF)
```

Neither of the delimiters worked. I wondered what exactly the ASCII code of the 'return' was so I made the following:

set rundates to "5/27/2012    5/28/2012    5/29/2012    5/30/2012    5/31/2012    6/1/2012    6/3/2012    6/4/2012    6/5/2012    6/6/2012    6/7/2012    6/8/2012    6/10/2012    6/11/2012"

```
 set mylist to {}

 repeat with z from 1 to count of characters of rundates
        copy (ASCII number (character z of rundates)) to end of mylist
   end repeat


 --return mylist ---{53, 47, 50, 55, 47, 50, 48, 49, 50, 13, 53, 47, 50, 56, 47, 50, 48, 49, 50, 13, 53, 47, 50, 57, 47, 50, 48, 49, 50, 13, 53, 47, 51, 48, 47, 50, 48, 49, 50, 13, 53, 47, 51, 49, 47, 50, 48, 49, 50, 13, 54, 47, 49, 47, 50, 48, 49, 50, 13, 54, 47, 51, 47, 50, 48, 49, 50, 13, 54, 47, 52, 47, 50, 48, 49, 50, 13, 54, 47, 53, 47, 50, 48, 49, 50, 13, 54, 47, 54, 47, 50, 48, 49, 50, 13, 54, 47, 55, 47, 50, 48, 49, 50, 13, 54, 47, 56, 47, 50, 48, 49, 50, 13, 54, 47, 49, 48, 47, 50, 48, 49, 50, 13, 54, 47, 49, 49, 47, 50, 48, 49, 50}
```

---===== Notice the 13s? So this should work right? ====---

So my delimiter using 13 should have worked, but it doesn't.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I get different results from your post of the ascii numbers. Actually now that applescript is unicode we use "id" now instead of ascii number. It seems your character is "8232". So use this in your code before you get the text items...

```
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to character id 8232
```

Comment: I recently ran across this recently with someone converting old text files.  regulus6633 posted his answer before I could get mine started, but you can also set multiple delimiters to catch most line endings, for example {return, linefeed, return & linefeed, character id 8233, character id 8232}.

Comment: If you are running Snow Leopard or later.